# What is the best way to split the string in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript, split

I have the string input something like

**Input**
text: string = "today lunch 200 #hotelname"

**Output**
subject: "today lunch"
price: 200
tag: #hotelname

my solution is

```
text: string = "today lunch 200 #hotelname"
  tag: string;
  price: string;
  subject: string;

 this.text.forEach(x => {
      if(this.reg.test(x)){
         this.tag= x;
      }else if(parseInt(x)){
          this.price = x;
      }
      else{
        this.subject= x;
      }
    });
 console.log(this.subject, this.tag, this.price);
```

but the problem is my solution is not satisfying all test cases is there any better solution using typescript or in javascript

**Test case**

1. the string cannot have two no
   ex 1: today lunch 200 #hotel 200
   ex 2: 200 food 2 0 1 #pasta
2. The text starts with # is treated as tag and cant have multiple tags in a
   string
3. if the string is like "food at xyz hotel 100 #chinies
   output: subject: "food at xyz hotel"
           price: 100
           tag: #chinies

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please share what you have tried yourself. You are expected to do some research before asking here.

Comment: fastest would be to write it yuorself rather than waiting for some generous fool to write it for you, because you don't know how long you'll need to wait

Answer (score 1):

use `match`:

```js
let string = "today lunch 200 #hotelname";

console.log(string.match(/(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(#.*)/))
```